# Wrong answer count for questions with deleted answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, 10k-tools

There is a slightly annoying new feature/bug that I first noticed one or two days ago and seems related to joriki's question [wrong answer count after an answer was deleted and undeleted](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1629/wrong-answer-count-after-an-answer-was-deleted-and-undeleted)

For instance, I see an answer count of $7$ answers on [How to show $e^{e^{e^{79}}}$ is not an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13054/how-to-show-eee79-is-not-an-integer) while there are only three answers plus four deleted ones. Now these four deleted answers are nothing but noise and I don't see the reason of counting them, or if they are counted I'd prefer seeing something like: 3 answers (+ 4 deleted answers).

The question [Measure of $R_d \times \{0\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56271/measure-of-r-d-times-0) only has GEdgar's answer and again a deleted one and I see this:

[image: Wrong answer count]

(The white rectangle is there because I edited out the "user card" of the poster of the deleted answer)

---

If I'm not logged in, the system behaves as it should and displays that there is only one answer:

[image: Correct answer count]

I don't think this only is "denormalization" (see Jeff's answer to joriki's question) as old posts with no activity in a long time display the same behavior.

Comment: @joriki: Freudian slip, I guess :) I'm so used to your answering questions...

Comment: Funny you should say that -- I was going to ask a question on meta about asking questions tomorrow :-)

Comment: Dear Theo, Good question!  (I just noticed this yesterday, I think, and was similarly puzzled.)  Best wishes,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design -- as a user with >= 10k rep, you can see deleted answers. So from *your* perspective, there are indeed two answers. One of them happens to be deleted.

Comment: Hm. Thanks, I feared that. But I don't think there are two *answers*. There is one answer and one piece of noise. But is this new? I don't think I've seen that before and it's been a while that I have >10K.

Comment: there were bugs in the old implementation based on using an incorrect answer count, actually -- that got fixed.

Comment: Okay, then I probably have no choice but to live with it :) Will manage that, I think. Thanks for the quick response and sorry to have wasted your time with such a triviality.

Comment: Hardly a triviality, I would rather have a community that cares *too much* than not at all!

Comment: @Jeff: would it be much work to change the display for 10K users to read `X answers (Y deleted)` or something like that?

Comment: Echoing Willie's request: would it take too much overhead for the software to count how many deleted answers are there in the question and display this accordingly?